# How to handle dynamic payment in in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

*We are working on online digital course purchase functionality in our mobile app with in-app purchase. Here, we are facing issues to handle dynamic payments like some user may apply discount coupon and final price vary based on coupon and the cart items. In this scenario how we can handle in-app purchase?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Google in-app billing doesn't support discount coupons.

Promotion codes can be created to buy the product  or subscription at no cost but not to buy it at a reduced price

It does not work like an online store, there is no shopping cart, the items are bought and paid one by one.